# Get a number out of a dummy string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
const   str = 'This is _XXX_0_ an example',
        target = ['just', 'nothing', 'bla'];
```

Now I need to get the number out of that string, as `_XXX_` Number `_` is a fixed format, to get the element which should replace the dummy string.

I tried this:

```
str.replace(/_XXX_(/d+)_/, target[$i]);
```

The number value could be something between 0 and 100. What am I doing wrong?

Result for this example is:

```
This is just an example
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted `/_XXX_(\d+)_/`? Isn't that just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this:
>
> ```
> str.replace(/_XXX_(/d+)_/, target[$i]);
> ```

Two problems there:

1. You want `\d`, not `/d`. The above is a syntax error.
2. `target[$i]` will be evaluated and then passed into `replace`. Presumably you'd get a `ReferenceError` on it, unless `$i` is defined somewhere.

You probably wanted to make that a function:

```
const result = str.replace(/_XXX_(\d+)_/, function(m, c0) {
    return target[c0];
});
```

The function receives the overall match as the first argument, then any capture groups as subsequent arguments.

Example:

```js
const   str = 'This is _XXX_0_ an example',
        target = ['just', 'nothing', 'bla'];
const result = str.replace(/_XXX_(\d+)_/, function(m, c0) {
        return target[c0];
    });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Isn't `$i` part of code not shown by OP? It is not `$1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Quite right, I misread it as `$1` (which would, as you know, be the correct token to use in a replacement *string* if you wanted the first capture group value).

Comment: Everything right. `$i` should be the extracted number. So this code works great. (Accepting not possible at the moment)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What do I have to do, if there are multiple matchings in the string?

Comment: Add a `/g` modifier: `/_XXX_(\d+)_/g`. And if you have overlapping matches, use `/_XXX_(\d+)(?=_)/g`

Comment: @user3142695: See Wiktor's comment above.